# JPA query returns Object[] instead of desired entity

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

I use this code to do a query to a sql server database:

```
List<Continent> continents = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object[]> tuples = (List<Object[]>) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Continents").getResultList();
        for (Object[] tuple : tuples) {

            System.out.println(tuple[0]);

        }
        return continents;
```

I use this code because I can't get the desired entity type (Continent) straight out of the database.

How should my query look like?

This is the start of my continent class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Continent implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private StringProperty name;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ContinentID")
    private IntegerProperty continentId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="continent")
    private Connection connection;
    List<Country> countries;


    public Continent(String naam) throws SQLException {
        name = new SimpleStringProperty(naam);
        continentId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    }

    protected Continent()
    {}
```

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="HOGENT1415_11" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>domain.Continent</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=HOGENT1415_11"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: This gives me this error: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'c'.

Comment: is `Continent` actually an `Entity`, i.e. is it annotated with `@Entity` and has property marked as `@Id`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited OP to show this

Comment: `createNativeQuery("normal sql query")`  and `createQuery("uses jpql")`

Comment: is `Continent` actually in `domain` package? since you explicitly specify `domain.Continent` class, you probably also need to specify `Connection` and `Country` as well. You also need to provide mapping information for `countries` property.

Comment: Yes, I added all, and how do you mean provide the mapping information?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that the entity is named Continents in the db, and the class name is Continent?

Comment: if the table is named differently, you need to provide it's name as `@Table(name = "Continents")`. countries probably should have `@OneToMany` annotation.

Answer (score 5):

You should provide resulting class, if you are using native query:

```
List<Continent> tuples = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Continents", Continent.class).getResultList();
```

or just use jpql query:

```
List<Continent> tuples = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Continent c", Continent.class).getResultList();
```

In second example result class is optional, but this way you get `TypedQuery` and can avoid casting. 
Note that in case of jpql you provide entity name, not table name like in native query.

Comment: Option 1 gives me Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class domain.Continent].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Continent sql="SELECT * FROM Continents")

Comment: Option 2 gives me Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT c FROM Continent c]. 
[14, 23] The abstract schema type 'Continent' is unknown.

Comment: there is probably an error in the configuration of your persistence unit then. how do you configure it? do you have persistence.xml, orm.xml or do you configure EntityManager factory in some other way?

Comment: I have persistence.xml

Comment: can you provide more info? what's inside persistence.xml, what's your environment - do you use it with ejb, spring application or standalone java se?

Comment: standalone java se, i will place the contents of the file in the OP.

Comment: We are also doing the same kind of mapping between the query result and java entity. The result of the query varies with the mysql version and hence the mapping sometimes throws an exception when the result does not conform to the entity schema. How to handle such a situation?


The query we are using is : **SHOW SLAVE STATUS;**

The exception: **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Column 'Gtid_IO_Pos' not found.**

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
for (Object[] tuple : tuples) 
{
   continents.add((Continent) tuple[0]));
}
```

To populate your list.

Edit:

Based on your comment you can do this instead:

```
for (Object[] tuple : tuples) 
{
    Continent c = new Continent();
    c.setID(tuple[0]);
    c.setName(tuple[1]);
    continents.add(c);
}
```

Comment: in tuple[0] is the id of the entity and in tuple[1] is the name of the entity ...

Comment: @HardUser I've updated my answer. You may need to change the setter methods to the names you've defined.

Comment: Yes I can do this as a workaround, but I rather have the entity straight out of the db

Answer (score 0):

For a simple query like this its better to just use em.createQuery rather than em.createNativeQuery, that is assuming that the class Continent is being managed by the entity manager em.

List continents = (List)em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Continent c").getResultList();